# how to override default values of a provisioner?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

i have a Vagrant file with multiple provision blocks like this:

```
config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file = "first.pp"
end

config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file = "second.pp"
end

config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file = "third.pp"
end
```

how can i eliminate the redundant `puppet.manifest_path`and `puppet.module_path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it walks like Ruby and talks like Ruby, so chances are you can

```
%w{first second third}.each do |manifest|
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path    = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "#{manifest}.pp"
  end
end
```

Note that you can specify a directory of manifests to be used, instead of a single file.